# Does absolutely uniform convergence imply uniform convergence ?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please give me some hint how to solve this problem:

Prove or provide counter-example:

If $\sum|f_n(x)|$ converges uniformly on some interval I then $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on I.

I have no idea how to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence if you know that.